# Same this pointer and trouble with variadic types

Tags: c++, c++11, this-pointer

I hope it's okay to just throw in a piece of code which I don't understand why it is behaving like it is.

I have two problems with the following code.

1) Why is the `this` pointer for the two instances showing the same value? Here the output of the program:

```
WJ::WJ(Jit&)
this = 0x7ffff1743950 JV<T, N>::JV(Jit&, indices<Is ...>) [with int ...Is = {0}; T = WJ<float>; int N = 1]
RS<T>::RS(Jit&) [with T = WJ<float>]
this = 0x7ffff1743950 JV<T, N>::JV(Jit&, indices<Is ...>) [with int ...Is = {0}; T = RS<WJ<float> >; int N = 1]
PS<T>::PS(Jit&) [with T = RS<WJ<float> >]
go for it
ptr = 0x7ffff1743950 JV<T, N>::JV(Jit&, JV<T, N>*, indices<Is ...>) [with int ...Is = {0}; T = RS<WJ<float> >; int N = 1]
PS<T>::PS(const PS<T>&) [with T = RS<WJ<float> >; PS<T> = PS<RS<WJ<float> > >]
```

It shows 2 times the value `0x7ffff1743950`. This wonders me because I am sure the first instance is not destroyed before the second is created.

2) I try to make deep copies of an `PS` where the `orig_ptr` are set to the original. The here used setup is a recursive template instantiation setup. So `orig_ptr` on each level should respect the hierarchy and point accordingly. What I don't understand is why does the code compile with `F{{(void(Is),j,ptr->F[Is])...}}` (it's marked in the code) and why does it not compile with `F{{(void(Is),j,&ptr->F[Is])...}}`? (which I would assume correct). I don't see which constructor of `T` (aka `RS<WJ<float> >`) the compiler is calling. There is no `RS<WJ<float> >::RS(Jit&,RS<WJ<float> >)` only the pointer version exists.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

struct Jit {};


template <int... Is>
struct indices {};

template <int N, int... Is>
struct build_indices
  : build_indices<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};

template <int... Is>
struct build_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...> {};


template<class T,int N>
struct JV {

  JV(Jit& j) : JV(j,build_indices<N>{}) {}
  template<int... Is>
  JV(Jit& j, indices<Is...>) : 
    jit(j), F{{(void(Is),j)...}} {
    std::cout << "this = " << (void*)this << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }


  JV(Jit& j,JV<T,N>* ptr) : JV(j,ptr,build_indices<N>{}) {}
  template<int... Is>
  JV(Jit& j,JV<T,N>* ptr, indices<Is...>) : 
    // Why does this not compile with &ptr->F[Is] ??
    // What is it calling now (there is no T::T(Jit&,sub_T))
    jit(j), orig_ptr(ptr), F{{(void(Is),j,ptr->F[Is])...}} {  
    std::cout << "ptr = " << (void*)ptr << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
  std::array<T,N> F;
  JV<T,N>* orig_ptr;
  Jit& jit;
};

template<class T>
struct RS : public JV<T,1>
{
  RS(Jit &j): JV<T,1>(j) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }

  RS(Jit &j, RS* orig): JV<T,1>(j,orig) {
    std::cout << "orig = " << orig << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

template<class T>
struct PS : public JV<T,1>
{
  PS(Jit& j): JV<T,1>(j) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }

  PS(const PS& rhs) : JV<T,1>(rhs.jit,const_cast<JV<T,1>*>(  static_cast<const JV<T,1>*>(&rhs) ) ) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

template<class T>
struct WJ
{
  WJ(Jit& j) {
    std::cout << "WJ::WJ(Jit&)\n";
  }
  WJ(Jit& j,WJ* ptr) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Jit j;
  PS<RS<WJ<float> > > w(j);
  std::cout << "go for it\n";
  PS<RS<WJ<float> > > wcopy(w);
}
```

** EDIT **

I added the pointer interface to `WJ` so that the instantiation procedure of `F` can recurse down the whole way. I thought it might be due to SFINE. But it wasn't.

Tried this with g++-4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-4precise1) 4.7.2 with `-O0`.

** EDIT **

@sehe's answer pointed me in the right direction. Of course, the `void(Is)` is not needed in the second type of `JV` constructors. Only in the first type, there it is used to simulate a `std::fill`. But there we are in the initializer list! The default implementation of the sequence operator helps to eliminate the `(void)Is` completely.

Now in the 2nd case there is another use of `Is`, namely in `ptr->F[Is]`, so no need to introduce the artificial `void`. Now, this looks better:

** EDIT **

```
JV(Jit& j,JV<T,N>* ptr, indices<Is...>) : 
    jit(j), orig_ptr(ptr), F{{T(j,&ptr->F[Is])...}} { }
```

It compile and runs fine now!

However, the 1 problem still remain: Why is `this` 2x the same ?!?

Answer (score 2):

The expansion of the template argument pack here:

```
F {{(void(Is),j,ptr->F[Is])...}}
```

is very creative, but not what you'd expect.

```
(void(Is),j,ptr->F[Is])
```

is a single expression, using the *sequence operator* (`operator,`). Which has roughly the same semantics as the following block of 'pseudo function':

```
{
    (void)Is;
    (void)j;
    return ptr->F[Is];
}
```

Note how `Is` and `j` don't have any other effect than sideeffects, which they have none. So the whole expression is equivalent to

```
F {{(ptr->F[Is])...}}
```

And to be honest, I failed to grasp the intent of your code. Here is a little proof of concept I did to verify whether the syntax you seem to be after **can** work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Vec;

template <int... I>
    void foo(Vec const& v)
{
    std::array<std::string, sizeof...(I)> expand {{ v.at(I)... }};
    for(auto i: expand)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    const Vec v { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "etc" };
    foo<2,1,3,0>(v);
    foo<42>(v);
}
```

Outputs:

```
two
one
three
zero
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

So, it does precisely what you'd expect (tested in GCC and Clang++)

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two prints with this = 0x7ffff1743950 appear before "go for it" they are from constructing w.  The one following "go for it" is coming from constructing copyw and I suspect you have additional output after that with this = .

In your JV type you a member:

```
std::array<T,N> F
```

and since both PS and RS inherit from JV the type supplied to JV, which processing PS is RS, which mean that the F in the JV that PS is derived from has a PS in which is derived from JV.